# remove indexes added by transpose using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading CSV file using `pandas`

```
data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
         header CGW added date Reference date      Project Activity
0  is_mandatory             no             no          yes       no
1      datatype            NaN            NaN         date      NaN
2        format            NaN            NaN  dd-mmm-yyyy      NaN
```

**After transpose:**

I have to transpose the data. I am transposing using `transpose()` method

```
data = data.transpose()
print(data)
```

Output:

```
                           0         1            2
header          is_mandatory  datatype       format
CGW added date            no       NaN          NaN
Reference date            no       NaN          NaN
Project                  yes      date  dd-mmm-yyyy
Activity                  no       NaN          NaN
```

But here, `header, CGW added date, Reference date, Project, Activity` became indexes. I want it as data not as index. How can I do the same? Do I have to add any property while reading CSV itself?

**Note: column names in CSV are not fix.**

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

`data.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Does this answer your question?